# How to add a new class to an html element in Xenforo

Tags: xml, edit, forum, xenforo

I'm using xenforo, and I've tried to add a class to an element that I want to be in a different place, it doesn't have a class by default.

I've tried to edit it in templates.xml but it's not changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have to go to **Appearance > *(Your theme)* > Templates**

from here you edit the specific template file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CSS template. And then in the template contains your element that you want to add new class, add the CSS template that you've just created with this statement:
`<xen:require css=“yourTemplate.css” />`.

That's it. Here some pictures to describe:

**First Step: Create CSS template**

[image]

**Second Step: Add it into your template**

[image]